# How to get the physical device that a volume GUID path belongs to?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, disk

I need to convert a volume GUID path to a physical drive path by using the `winapi`.

I listed the volumes on my PC by using `FindFirstVolume`/`FindNextVolume` and I get the following output:

```
First volume found: \\?\Volume{42f73c69-4b40-11e9-a0b2-806e6f6e6963}\
Found next volume:  \\?\Volume{8aef5fee-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
Found next volume:  \\?\Volume{8aef5fee-0000-0000-0000-90c30b000000}\
Found next volume:  \\?\Volume{8aef5fee-0000-0000-0000-501f1e000000}\
Found next volume:  \\?\Volume{ec716472-e587-11e8-a031-806e6f6e6963}\
Search finished: [18] There are no more files.
```

I need to know the physical device each volume belongs to, like `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1`

There is my code:

```c
/* This program attempts to list the volumes and get the corresponding physical device for each one */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE openDevice(const char *deviceID);
BOOL getAllVolumes();

/* Main function
   * Access the device
   * Get all volume GUID paths
   * Close handler
*/
int main()
{
    char *deviceID = "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1";
    HANDLE hDevice = openDevice(deviceID);
    if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { /* success */
        fprintf(stderr, "Device %s opened.\n", deviceID);
        /* find all volumes in the device and get the corresponding device to each one */
        BOOL result = getAllVolumes();
        CloseHandle(hDevice); /* close the handler to the device */
    }

    return 0;
}

HANDLE openDevice(const char *deviceID)
{
    /* Access the device */
    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFileA(
        deviceID, /* device id (get it with `$ wmic DISKDRIVE`) */
        FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA, /* read/write access */
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, /* shared */
        NULL, /* default security attributes */
        OPEN_EXISTING, /* only open if the device exists */
        0, /* file attributes */
        NULL); /* do not copy file attributes */

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { /* cannot open the physical drive */
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the device %s: [%lu]\n", deviceID, errorCode); /* print the error code and message */
    }

    return hDevice;
}

BOOL getAllVolumes()
{
    char volumePath[512] = {0};
    fprintf(stderr, "Attempt to find first volume...\n");
    HANDLE searchHandlerDevice = FindFirstVolume(volumePath, sizeof(volumePath));
    fprintf(stderr, "Done. Retrieving results...\n");
    if (searchHandlerDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find a volume: [%lu]\n", errorCode); /* print the error code and message */
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "First volume found: %s\n", volumePath);
    }

    /* find the other volumes */
    while (FindNextVolume(searchHandlerDevice, volumePath, sizeof(volumePath))) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Found volume: %s\n", volumePath);
    }

    /* searching failed */
    DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Search failed: [%lu]\n", errorCode); /* print the error code and message */

    /* close the search */
    BOOL result = FindVolumeClose(searchHandlerDevice);
    if (!result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Search failed: [%lu]\n", errorCode); /* print the error code */
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you can call for this `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` and use `DeviceNumber` for format *PhysicalDrive%u*. but this ioctl handled only for volume/disk devices. the `FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume` by unknown reason add \ to the end. as result this already not volume path but root folder path. need remove last \ before open file

Comment: @RbMm, `FindNextVolumeW` adds the backslash for consistency since it's required in a junction mountpoint, else opening the junction (e.g. `SetCurrentDirectoryW`) without a trailing backslash would open the volume device instead of the filesystem root directory. We also get the volume name with a trailing backslash from `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW`. `SetVolumeMountPointW` also requires it and passes it through to a junction (but not a DOS drive mountpoint since the object symbolic link has to target the volume device).

Comment: @RbMm, that said, I think they went the wrong way with maintaining consistency. Adding the backslash, where required, should have been an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @eryksun unfortunatelly with slash at the end we got not volume but directory file object. but file systems accept ioctl only for user volume opens, as result `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` and `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` fail here with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. possible of course direct use `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS`.. but question for what all this need at all. maybe more correct way first enumerate disks, that partitions on it. hard say how better, without know real task

Comment: @RbMm, note that some volumes may be CD/DVD drives (i.e. `DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM`), in which case we don't need the enumerated physical device name, but if we want it, the template is `"CdRom%d"`.

Comment: Also, `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` will (or should?) fail if a volume spans multiple disks, in which case we need `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` to list all of the disk extents. The new storage spaces is implemented differently, however. It combines volumes (which are not assigned a GUID name) into a new disk device, and the visible volume uses this single disk.

Comment: @eryksun yes, unfortunatelly i never check case where volume have multiple extens on different disks. however here question  for me src of task. for what need get disk from all mounted volumes ? may be better do reverse task - enumerate all disks, than all partions on disk. but i have no experience when volume != single partition

Comment: @RbMm, I had a spare moment, so I created a spanned volume from two disks in a VM. As I expected, getting `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` for the volume failed with `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` (i.e. `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`). I had to get the disk numbers from `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`.

Comment: @eryksun so can assume that `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` is obsolete in general case. and need use only `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` . and no single disk in general case for volume.

Comment: @eryksun - in this case i assume volume != partition. we can enumerate partitions for every disk. but this volume have several partitions in set (frequently volume and partition is confused)

Comment: @eryksun - what is interesing to look in this case - usualy \Device\HarddiskX\PartitionY is symbolic link to volume device \Device\HarddiskVolumeZ, but in case partition is only part of volume - to what it point if look in winobj ?

Comment: @RbMm, the two disks aren't partitioned, i.e. we only have the "Partition0" symlink to the disk itself, e.g. "\Device\Harddisk3\Partition0" -> "\Device\Harddisk3\DR3". The disk management snapin displays a warning regarding accessibility from other operating systems.

Comment: @eryksun thank for info. are impossible have several partitions on pthysical disk, part of which is usual volume and some is part of comlex multi-partition volume ? in usual case we can have several partition on disk.

Comment: @RbMm, I wouldn't call `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` obsolete. It's supported by more device types such as CDROMs (in this case the partition number is -1).

Comment: @RbMm, I used diskpart.exe to test a more complex layout. I started with 2 GPT dynamic disks, each having the 1 MB "Dynamic Reserved" database partition (anonymous partition 1). On each, I created a partition with half the disk. I then extended each partition into the free space on the other dynamic disk. This created two crisscrossed volumes from the 2 disks, but there's only 1 "Dynamic Data" partition (anonymous partition 3) on each disk.  Each also got a small reserved "Partition2" (not anonymous). I don't know what it's used for; it's not the dynamic-disk database.

Comment: Note that I'm not recommending using dynamic disks. It's just something that needs to be considered. Dynamic disks have been replaced by Storage Spaces. As I mentioned several comments ago, storage spaces is different. It combines hidden (i.e. no GUID name) volume devices back into a new basic disk, which has the normal partition-volume relationship that works with `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer in the [DiskDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive) class. It represents a physical disk drive as seen by a computer running the Windows operating system.